# Android Studio setting node directory for build (Cause: error=2, No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

My project build fails because it's using the incorrect directory to run Node. How do I go about setting the Node directory for these compile-time tasks?

The specific task is:

> app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug

And the related error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug'.
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node''
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'node'
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/Users/me/Code/appname/android/app"): error=2, No such file or directory
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: I also suffer this issue :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to the build.gradle if you use React-Native

```
ext {    
    react = [
        nodeExecutableAndArgs:  ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Should I put into app level `build.gradle` or in project level `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Ajay   project/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: that would force all developers to have node in that location, though, right?

Comment: @NieSelam maybe you can set it to a different location

Comment: @Yoruba true but the file gets comitted to git so next developer will have to change it. In my case anyway, the issue was in the installation. I removed all and installed first java then android studio then react native.

Answer (score 33):

I am running Android Studio on MacOS and following worked for me: Yoruba's answer above and starting the application from Terminal with `open -a "Android Studio.app"`

Comment: this method worked for me (M1 chip). don't know what's wrong with android studio and M1. it's sucks!

Comment: Another M1 too. But that certainly works. Can you provide information about why it's working that way?

Comment: It worked for me too, but I do not have M1, this is my processor: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Any reason, why it's working this way?

Answer (score 24):

It is a known bug for the environment:

- Apple chip M1
- Android Studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Upgrade to Gradle version 6.9 or above in the gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-all.zip
```

https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/release-notes.html

Comment: This is the right answer for those on M1 chips.

Comment: Also had to set the correct gradle plugin version from the [compatibility table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) to `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")` in the root `build.gradle` file.

Comment: This is the correct and working answer after a lot of tries, thanks a lot!

Comment: Phew...!! After several different attempts, finally this seems to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find the node path in your system using command

`which node` inside terminal
Then open `app/build.gradle` and add this line

```
ext {    
    react = [
        nodeExecutableAndArgs:  ["Node path from the above command"]
    ]
}
```

After that it may ask to upgrade kotlin version then add this in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        ext {
            kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by installing node.js again because the react was not able to find it.