# How to open Android Studio via Terminal If we have two different version

Tags: android-studio

I have two Android Studio versions in my MAC. They are `Android Studio Dolphin` and `Android Studio 4.2.2`. This is how they appear in **Applications**

[image]

Following is the command to open Android Studio from Terminal,

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

But this command always opens the first version installed.

May I know how to run specific version of Android Studio from Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

`open -a "Android Studio.app"`.

Here we can replace the `Android Studio` with what ever the name, like in my case `Android Studio 2`

I found this working solution here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974833/8364900